# Google Maps: Hide country borders

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm pretty sure `geometry.stroke` option allowed to hide country borders on the map.

```
     {
        featureType: "administrative.country",
        elementType: "geometry.stroke",
        stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
        ]
      }
```

But today I was wondering that's not working as expected, I still see the borders.
Here is a code example: http://jsfiddle.net/xuvffdsn/

Any suggestions how to hide country borders?

Comment: Yeah, same for me. Google must have made a change on their side this morning.

Comment: Looks like a bug, being tracked @ https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7165

Answer (score 5):

The fiddle you provided seems to work correctly for me (in that it hides the borders). I am able to turn country borders on and off. Here is your example updated so that the country borders are shown: http://jsfiddle.net/jkgudhze/. For me, this definitely adds the borders that were missing. I was able to show them by changing `{ stylers: [ { visibility: "off" } ] }` in your code to `{ stylers: [ { visibility: "off" } ] }`. Is there any chance that what you are seeing are state / region borders?

Comment: As bamnet mentioned in the comments this was a bug which is fixed now. For more details see code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7165

Comment: My bad. I think I overlooked the date of the original question. How should this question be closed to avoid additional answers?

Comment: There is an off topic reason related to questions where "the problem can no longer be reproduced". If this issue is from a now fixed bug, then the question would seem to fit that category