# Is it possible to style country borders and coast lines on Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I prepared a jfiddle with only country borders in order to help you and all styles resetted:

```
var styles = [
  {
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zsuan1c3/

I'd like to change colour of both country borders and coast lines!
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps: Hide country borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990252/google-maps-hide-country-borders)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit – august 2021**

Google Maps API V3 currently accepts `administrative.country` directive for styling country borders.

```json
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.country",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ff0000"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Directive for coastlines is unfortunately not supported.

---

**Original answer**

There is an issue with the API:

[Issue 7165:    Bug: Cannot hide country borders anymore (since 9/24/14)](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7165)

`administrative.country.geometry` elements seem to accept no styling at all.

related question: [Google Maps: Hide country borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990252/google-maps-hide-country-borders)

Comment: It still answers the question so I see no reason for downvoting.

Comment: This is the answer I needed. You can not always find a solution to everything. I have a client who wanted to know if it was me who did not know how to do that or it's one thing that it's impossible to do. Now I have the answer: there is a bug so it cannot be done at the moment and now the customer is settled. Thanks to geocodezip.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still stumbling on this thread as I did and looking for ways to customize Google Maps look and feel, here is the Google Devs explanation on how to do so

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference

Also, here is a great web app to customize the map and see the results in live.
https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/